# how to call another application using objective c

Tags: objective-c, openurl

using objective c code to call third party application. actually i already check many of the application but not able to call third party app. i am not able to find URL Scheme of any app that installed from APP Store. like Twitter application have twitter:// url scheme.

```
      NSString *customURL = @"twitte://";

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"URL error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                 @"No custom URL defined for %@", customURL]
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no public/official API for directly opening **any** application unless it has specified a URL scheme.

**However,** if using a private API is an option for you, then try the `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier()` function from the SpringBoardServices framework. Usage:

```
int errorCode = SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(@"com.myapp.bundleid", NO);
if (errorCode != 0) {
    CFStringRef errMsg = SBSApplicationLaunchingErrorString(errorCode);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply....i already try to call my own another app with URL scheme and it can be able to call easily but the problem is if i install from app store that app can not be able to call by code because i don't have URL scheme of that app.. is there any way to call that apps also.....

Comment: @ArvindKumarChoubey In all honesty, did you ***READ*** my answer??